# How to get the full range of output voltage (0-5V) from a differential pair circuit as a schmitt trigger?

Tags: schmitt-trigger

The circuit works in the hysteresis range of 2.5V - 1.5V. The output voltage does not reach the full range because I have a dc offset of 1.8V. What's the easiest way to get the full output range with this kind of circuit? Adding a capacitor removes dc offset, but I need another gain stage to get the 0-5V output... Thanks

[image]

Comment: *The output voltage does not reach the full range* Think about what the lowest output voltage will be when using this circuit. Hint: assume Q1 is open (not conducting) and Q2 is closed (fully conducting), then I see a voltage divider, do you too? *What's the easiest way to get the full output range with this kind of circuit?* There is no way, this circuit cannot do it. Explain why you don't use an **opamp** (or comparator) to make a Schmitt-trigger like almost everyone else.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I design this as part of the exercise, but as a circuit at the clock input.